# Data flow runs 5 times slower on Production

Tags: sql-server, ssis

The same data flow in a SSIS package runs 5 times slower on Production Server.

On Dev, the data flow shifts data from a Development database to text file on a network folder. On the Development Server this process runs in 1 second per file . So ADO.NET Source to Flat File destination with nothing else.

On Production, (exactly the same data), the data flow shifts data from a Production Database to text file on the same network folder . On Production the same process runs in 5 seconds per file. Again ADO.net source to Flat File destination.

Now obvious difference is the database. Nothing else is different apart from the server the SSIS package is running from.

So what is the best way to determine the bottleneck ? Should I separate the source and destination in the data flow to determine which part has the problem. Can I increase the packet size or use fast parse on the flat file to speed things up ? Is there a quicker way to work out the problem? On Prod I am limited to what I can test. This is the only place the problem happens. Will Performance counters help me ? Is there a special diagnostics package someone has that may help?

A lot of ideas come flowing to my head. The question to focus on is how to work out what the bottleneck is in less than 5 minutes ?

Comment: Are the record counts different?

Comment: Which version of SQL Server?  Is there an index on your dev database that isn't on production?  Have you updated statistics lately?  Are you indexes fragmented?  Any differences in network speeds, latency, etc.?

Comment: Did you run the source queries against database outside ssis on dev and prod server?

Comment: Sql server 2008. Both queries that are used to get the data to put in text files complete in less than 1 second. Indexes are fine and not fragmented. I am not sure how to determine network speed,  ping ? How do you measure latency ? Queries were against database outside of ssis on dev and prod server.

Comment: Record counts identical.

Comment: Is a 25 second difference in package execution crucial to the success of your project?

Comment: Are both production and dev machines physical machines? Another point, is the production server low on available memory?

Comment: It is hundreds of files so the time difference adds up . Will check said server and database server to see if it's low on available memory.

Comment: Break the problem down until you can't break it down any more. Is it the network? Change the destination to local disk. Is it still 5x slower? Yes, then it's not network related. Is is database related - get the *actual* execution plan from production and one from your dev system: are they the exact same? Etc